# Syncronise Oracle APEX Calendar form with Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar-api, oracle-apex

I try to sync my Oracle APEX Calendar form with my Google Calendar.
I created Google Calendar API Key as you can see in the picture
[image]

What else should i do, in order to send to Google Calendar my entries from my APEX form Calendar.
Also i want to update this entries (sync).
Can i do this with DA?

Comment: Hi ! Are you using [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar) to insert this APEX calendar into Google Calendar? If you could you please provide a sample code with no sensitive data on how you are performing this action? Thanks !

Comment: Hi Mateo and thank you for your response, i just enter the API Key to Shared Components > Component Settings > Calendar to set the key for the application. Do i have to do something else?

Comment: Where are you exactly peroforming this action ? On GCP or on APEX? What is your intention, to take one calendar you have hosted somewhere else and import it into Google Calendar?

Comment: On APEX and i want to take all the records of my APEX Calendar form into Google Calendar.

Comment: What is stopping you then from exporting your APEX calendar and importing it into Google Calendar as [explained in the Google Calendar guides](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37118?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)?

Comment: The problem is that i want to synchronize these to calendars, because I want new events to be automatically transferred from APEX to Google Calendar. Otherwise every time the user create a new entry in the APEX, will have to manually export from APEX and import to Google Calendar

Answer (score 0):

In the Calendar Attributes (in APEX) do this:

In the "Google Calendar ID" attribute enter the Google Calendar ID for the calendar data feed you would like to display on this calendar.

Given Google Calendars security restrictions, these calendars must either be public calendars, or available to all end users of this calendar.

Note: The Google Calendar API Key must be entered for Google calendars to work correctly. Go to Shared Components > Component Settings > Calendar to set the key for the application.

Examples
Google Calendar ID : abc123@group.calendar.google.com

Comment: Hi Gaspar and thank you for your response! I am using my Google Calengar ID : gl......@gmail.com (it is the same with my email). I try to use this as an ID, but nothing happens. I also change gl....@gmail.com to gl...@group.calendar.google.com still nothing happens, Of course Google Calendar API Key it is set to my application (see the picture)